# Storing additional data in aspnet_profile table with Membership data

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

I am using Membership API with OpenId implementation in my project built on MVC2 framework. 
Other than the username , I need some other fields to be associated with the user at the time of registration.

I am not sure though but I think Profile system in asp.net is built for this type of requirement.  Also, I see a table with other membership tables named 'aspnet_profile'.

I added following settings in the application web.config to enable the profile :

```
<profile enabled="true">
      <properties>
        <add  name="FullName" allowAnonymous="false"/>

      </properties>

    </profile>
```

As said before, application need some additional data to be associated with the user, so when creating a user using Membership API, I added few more lines of code for making entry into profile table

```
System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus status = MembershipService.CreateUser(userModel.UserName, userModel.Password, userModel.UserName);

                   if (status == System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                   {
                       FormsService.SignIn(userModel.UserName, true);
                       Session["Username"] = userModel.UserName;

                       dynamic profile = ProfileBase.Create(MembershipService.GetUser(userModel.UserName).UserName);
                       profile.FullName = userModel.UserFullName;
                       profile.Save();

                       RedirectToAction("Tech", "Home");



                   }
```

But I don't see any line added in the aspnet_profile table in the database. Also, I wanted to ask if this is the preferred way of adding additional data along with default membership data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made it work by making some changes related to default profile provider name in the web.config:

```
<profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" />
      </providers>

      <properties>
        <add  name="FullName" allowAnonymous="false"/>

      </properties>

    </profile>
```

Also I added one more line between call to ProfileBase.Create function  and setting the Profile.FullName;

```
profile.Initialize(userModel.userName, true);
```

I finally saw an entry in the aspnet_profile table for the newly registered user :)

Answer (score 1):

1, you need to create a profile class to define the profile structure

2, you need to config your profile settings in web.config as

3, now you can use your code now.

you just need to do the first 2 steps before you using it.

ref: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/19/writing-a-custom-asp-net-profile-class.aspx

Comment: I don't want to create a separate profile class for this. I think I am missing a setting in web.config. I don't think it's necessary to create a profile class to make this work

Answer (score 1):

While using ASP.NET profile provider, [profile properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx) is the way to customize the user profile. However, you don't have to create and save profile instance by yourself - it is done by ASp.NET runtime it-self. Use either [HttpContext.Current.Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.profile.aspx) or use strongly typed dynamic `Profile` property from the page it self. By using later, you can write code such as

```
Profile.UserName = "User Name";
```

There is no need to call `Save` method. For more information see [this article](http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx).

In a web application, one cannot really refer to dynamically created Profile class, so you have to work with `HttpContext.Current.Profile` (you can of course assign it to a `dynamic` variable for more readable code as done by you). Another way is to write [your own class](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/19/writing-a-custom-asp-net-profile-class.aspx).

Comment: MVC does not give you HttpContext.Current , you can directly access profile class using HttpContext.Profile

Comment: @Kunal, `HttpContext.Profile` is an instance property, so you need an instance of HttpContext which is typically available via `HttpContext.Current` in any ASP.NET application (including ASP.NET MVC)!

Comment: @VinayC He means to say that in an MVC `Controller` or `View` class, there is a `HttpContext` property, which is basically a wrapper for `HttpContext.Current`.